# Is there a way for me to irrigate my crops?

Tags: starbound

I have a number of crops which when I'm home I notice the soil beneath them seems to dry up mid growth requiring me to water them by hand.

When I go off exploring other planets or underground, I want to come back to my home and find that my crops are ready for harvest, not find them mid growth and not having grown for hours.

So is there a way for me to irrigate my crops so that I don't have to worry about watering them for extended periods of time?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [sprinklers](http://starbounder.org/Sprinkler).

> When placed it spreads water over an area of 15 blocks in both
>   directions, (covering a total of 32 blocks, 30 not counting the
>   sprinkler itself), which will prepare soil for crops to grow.

They will water whether you are there or not. Just make sure they meet the spacing requirements.

Comment: Sprinkler's are irrigation